# Codeigniter Bootstrap Markdown textarea

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4, http-post, textarea, markdown

I am having issues implementing Bootstrap Markdown in CodeIgniter 3.1.9.
I get it to pass and display data from a query in a view just fine as long as its a simple in form_input(). An issue arises when I attempt to post data from a form_textarea() wired up to Bootstrap Markdown with an id="bs-markdown"

Here is a partial of the view:

```html
                <div class="card-body"> 
                <?php echo form_open(site_url("admin/edit_user/".$user->id."/"));?>                 
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <?php echo lang('edit_user_fname_label', 'first_name', array('class' => 'form-label'));?>
                    <?php echo form_input($first_name, 'first_name' , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'first_name'));?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <?php echo lang('edit_user_lname_label', 'last_name', array('class' => 'form-label'));?>
                    <?php echo form_input($last_name, 'last_name' , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'last_name'));?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <?php echo lang('edit_user_company_label', 'company', array('class' => 'form-label'));?>
                    <?php echo form_input($company, 'comnpany' , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'company'));?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <?php echo lang('edit_user_vat_label', 'vat', array('class' => 'form-label'));?>
                    <?php echo form_input($vat, 'vat' , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'vat'));?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <?php echo lang('edit_user_email_label', 'email', array('class' => 'form-label'));?>
                    <?php echo form_input($email, 'email' , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email'));?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <?php echo lang('edit_user_phone_label', 'phone', array('class' => 'form-label'));?>
                    <?php echo form_input($phone, 'phone' , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone'));?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-12"">
                    <label class="form-label">Status</label>
                    <select class="custom-select">
                      <option selected="">Active</option>
                      <option>Suspended</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>                  
          <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">
            <h6 class="card-header">Notes on Customer</h6>    
            <div class="card-body py-0 px-0">                   
                <?php echo form_textarea('notes',$notes, array('id' => 'bs-markdown'));?>
            </div>                  
          </div>                  
        </div>    
    </div>
    <?php echo form_hidden('id', $user->id);?>
    <?php echo form_hidden($csrf); ?>
    <div class="text-right mt-3">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    
    <?php echo form_close();?>
  </div>
  <!-- / Content -->
  
  <script>
      // Bootstrap Markdown
      $(function() {
        $('#bs-markdown').markdown({
          iconlibrary: 'fa',
          footer: '<div id="md-character-footer"></div><small id="md-character-counter" class="text-muted">600 character left</small>',

          onChange: function(e) {
            var contentLength = e.getContent().length;

            if (contentLength > 600) {
              $('#md-character-counter')
                .removeClass('text-muted')
                .addClass('text-danger')
                .html((contentLength - 600) + ' character surplus.');
            } else {
              $('#md-character-counter')
                .removeClass('text-danger')
                .addClass('text-muted')
                .html((600 - contentLength) + ' character left.');
            }
          },
        });

        // Update character counter
        $('#markdown').trigger('change');


        // *******************************************************************
        // Fix icons

        $('.md-editor .fa-header').removeClass('fa fa-header').addClass('fas fa-heading');
        $('.md-editor .fa-picture-o').removeClass('fa fa-picture-o').addClass('far fa-image');
      });
  </script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
/**
 * Edit a user
 *
 * @param int|string $id
 */
public function edit_user($id)
{
    // Retrieves the operating Users data as Object which is passed to _navbar
    $this->data['operator'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();

    $user = $this->ion_auth->user($id)->row();

    // validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('edit_user_validation_fname_label'), 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('edit_user_validation_lname_label'), 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('edit_user_validation_phone_label'), 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('edit_user_validation_email_label'), 'trim|required');

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {
        
        // do we have a valid request?
        if ($this->_valid_csrf_nonce() === FALSE || $id != $this->input->post('id'))
        {
            show_error($this->lang->line('error_csrf'));
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
        {
            
            
            //echo var_dump($_POST);
            //exit();
            
            $data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'company' => $this->input->post('company'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'notes' => $this->input->post('bs'),


            );
            

            // check to see if we are updating the user
            if ($this->ion_auth->update($user->id, $data))
            {
                // redirect them back to the admin page if admin, or to the base url if non admin
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                redirect('admin/edit_user/'.$id, 'refresh');    

            }
            else
            {
                // redirect them back to the admin page if admin, or to the base url if non admin
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                redirect('admin/edit_user/'.$id, 'refresh');

            }

        }
    }   

    // set the flash data error message if there is one
    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

    // pass the user to the view
    $this->data['user'] = $user;        

    $this->data['first_name'] = array(
        'name'  => 'first_name',
        'id'    => 'first_name',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name', $user->first_name),
        
    );
    $this->data['last_name'] = array(
        'name'  => 'last_name',
        'id'    => 'last_name',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name', $user->last_name),
    );
    $this->data['company'] = array(
        'name'  => 'company',
        'id'    => 'company',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('company', $user->company),
    );
    $this->data['vat'] = array(
        'name'  => 'vat',
        'id'    => 'vat',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('vat', $user->vat),
    );
    $this->data['email'] = array(
        'name'  => 'email',
        'id'    => 'email',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email', $user->email),
    );
    $this->data['phone'] = array(
        'name'  => 'phone',
        'id'    => 'phone',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('phone', $user->phone),
    );
    
    $this->data['notes'] = $user->notes;        
    
    // display the edit user form
    $this->data['csrf'] = $this->_get_csrf_nonce();


    // VIEW: PARTIALS & TEMPLATE
    $partials['_dev_bar']  = $this->load->view('_dev_bar', NULL, TRUE);     
    $partials['navbar']    = $this->load->view('admin/modules/_navbar', $this->data, TRUE);             
    $partials['sidenav']   = $this->load->view('admin/modules/_sidenav', NULL, TRUE);
    $partials['content']   = $this->load->view('admin/modules/_body-user-customer-edit', NULL, TRUE);
    $partials['bottomnav'] = $this->load->view('admin/modules/_bottomnav', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('admin/_admin-template', $partials);
}   


/**
 * @return array A CSRF key-value pair
 */
public function _get_csrf_nonce()
{
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $key = random_string('alnum', 8);
    $value = random_string('alnum', 20);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfkey', $key);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfvalue', $value);

    return array($key => $value);
}

/**
 * @return bool Whether the posted CSRF token matches
 */
public function _valid_csrf_nonce(){
    $csrfkey = $this->input->post($this->session->flashdata('csrfkey'));
    if ($csrfkey && $csrfkey === $this->session->flashdata('csrfvalue')){
        return TRUE;
    }
        return FALSE;
}

public function redirectUser(){
    if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()){
        redirect('admin', 'refresh');
    }
    redirect('/', 'refresh');
}
```

A var_dump($Post) reveals that notes is not even posted to the array:

```
array(9) { 
   ["first_name"]=> string(7) "Johnwww" 
   ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Ddddd" 
   ["company"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["vat"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["email"]=> string(12) "john@doe.com" 
   ["phone"]=> string(8) "07009090" 
   ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
   ["91EnDeLb"]=> string(20) "0ibAqJsuo9mkVzKlRrEy" 
   ["submit"]=> string(6) "Update" 
}
```

If I omit referencing bootstrap markdown as an id="bs-markdown" in the textarea of the view them the var_dump() includes the item ["notes"]=> string(5) "notes"

Any pointer on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: fyi codeigniter has it's own CSRF system that is pretty good. anyways if this plugin is anything like CKeditor or the like, the contents aren't posted by default and can be gotten via some function. This usually makes it easy for ajax, but a pain for regulator posting. I'm not sure how you would do it in this plugin. However as doesn't seem to  be actively maintained I would switch to something like CK, tinymce, or my favorite - summernote

Comment: I did end up using summernote, with success. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with (and you may find better) is to do this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
 var textarea = $('#bs-markdown');
 var value = $('#bs-markdown').data('markdown').getContent();
 $('#some_hidden_field').attr('value', value);
});
```

Where `some_hidden_field` is a blank hidden field.

Applying it the `bs-markdown` value yielded nothing in post.

But again, I would suggest using a different, more actively maintained editor.

Comment: I ended up using a different, more maintained editor; summernote. And it posts properly. Thanks for the tip! <3